# What is the role of the mass Casimir invariant in Galilean and what it's actual role in special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, galilean-relativity, poincare-symmetry, invariants

What is the role of the (mass) Casimir invariant of the algebra of relativistic symmetries in Galilean and what it's actual role in special relativity?